# Assigning values to character A-Z in python

Tags: python, ascii

I am noobie. I am trying to assign values from A to Z. 
This is very long.

```
   A= 97
   B= 98
   C= 99
   D= 100
   ...
   Z= 122
```

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: don't create variables like this. Why would you do that?

Comment: You don't need the assigments. There's `ord('A'.lower())`

Comment: You can use the `ord(str)` function

Comment: Once you have these variables, what are you intending to do with them?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Why not simply [`ord('a')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord)? Why the `lower()`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Because `A -> 65`, `a -> 97`

Comment: Why would you want to do this? You could use a dictionary instead; `from string import ascii_lowercase`, then `lettermapping = {l: i for i, l in enumerate(ascii_lowercase, 97)}`. Or better still, just use the [`ord()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: because the OP used uppercase letters for the variables, but then used the ASCII codepoints for the lowercase letters..

Comment: Okay, let's just forget about ASCII value and string comparison. Could you tell me how to assign values from A-Z in an easier way?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like that:

```
import string

alpha_dict = {k: ord(k) for k in string.ascii_lowercase}
print(alpha_dict)  # {'r': 114, 'l': 108, 'z': 122, ...}
```

And access your variables like `alpha_dict['a']`.

---

Note that the values you have in your example correspond to the **lowercase** letters but you are naming your variables with **uppercase**. If you actually want the uppercase, instead of looping through `ascii_lowercase` loop over `ascii_uppercase`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hard-coding every letter you can use `ord('letter')`. For example `ord('a')` will return the number `97` which stands for the letter `a` in ASCII.

EDIT:

I used the code of [Ev. Kounis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45985285/6869922) for producing the dictionary because mine was wrong. If there's any problem I can delete it.

```
import string

alpha_dict = {k: ord(k) for k in string.ascii_uppercase}

'''Iterates in keys of alpha_dict, turning the key to lowercase, removes 
 the old key and replaces it with the new lowercase one'''
for key in alpha_dict:
    lower = key.lower()
    alpha_dict[lower] = alpha_dict.pop(key)

print(alpha_dict)
```

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't clear. I wanted to put an ASCII value of 'a' in 'A'. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: @ShikhaNepal Check my edit, I think it does what you need.